# My dropdown is not displaying icons of bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, navigation

````
```<nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="drop-down"><a href="/pre-engineered-steel-buildings">Pre Engineered Building</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/industrial-steel-building">Industrial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/commercial-building">MultiStoried Commercial Buildings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/industrial-warehouse-construction">Warehouse</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/institutional-building">Institutional Building</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="drop-down"><a href="/turnkey-contractors">Turnkey Solutions</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/civil-construction-work">Civil Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/heavy-steel-structures">Heavy Steel Structures</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="drop-down"><a href="/roofing-system">Roofing Solutions</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/standing-seam-roof-contractors">Standing Seam Roof Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/colour-coated-roofing-sheets-manufacturer">Color Coated Roofing Sheets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/insulated-roofing-sheets-manufacture">Insulated Roof System</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/trussless-roofing-system">Trussless Roof System</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/deck-sheets-manufacturer">Deck Sheets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/polycarbonate-sheets-manufacturer">Polycarbonate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/turbo-ventilators-manufacturer">Turbo Ventilators</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/peb-solutions-hospital-buildings">Covid-19 PreFab Cabin</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> ```
````

Done using Bootstrap. the arrow icons and the burger icons are NOT visible. only a box is shown in desktop & nothing in the mobile version.

[Desktop Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLmW.jpg)

[Phone navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEZsT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing a number of the Bootstrap components, such as the toggle anchor tags for the dropdowns. It’s best to stick with Bootstrap’s standard menu system.

Also, as Bootstrap uses the top menu item on a dropdown as the button to activate the toggle, you can’t use it as a link to a page. I moved your links to the first item in the dropdown.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Pre Engineered Building
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/pre-engineered-steel-buildings">Pre Engineered Building</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/industrial-steel-building">Industrial</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/commercial-building">MultiStoried Commercial Buildings</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/industrial-warehouse-construction">Warehouse</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/institutional-building">Institutional Building</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Turnkey Solutions
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/turnkey-contractors">Turnkey Solutions</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/civil-construction-work">Civil Works</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/heavy-steel-structures">Heavy Steel Structures</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Roofing Solutions
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/roofing-system">Roofing Solutions</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/standing-seam-roof-contractors">Standing Seam Roof Systems</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/colour-coated-roofing-sheets-manufacturer">Color Coated Roofing Sheets</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/insulated-roofing-sheets-manufacture">Insulated Roof System</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/trussless-roofing-system">Trussless Roof System</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/deck-sheets-manufacturer">Deck Sheets</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/polycarbonate-sheets-manufacturer">Polycarbonate</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/turbo-ventilators-manufacturer">Turbo Ventilators</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/peb-solutions-hospital-buildings">Covid-19 PreFab Cabin</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Covid-19 PreFab Cabin</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It's best, when asking a question, to use the snippet tool. That way, you can see if you have enough of your code in the question.

Comment: The dropdown icons come in the desktop version. But, the dropdown functionality doesn't seem to work.
In mobile view, there is NO burger icon & the navigations list is always visible, as a dropdown list on the right side of the screen.

Comment: In works in my snippet (there is a burger icon and the dropdowns are on the left) - try comparing what you have with my snippet.

Comment: Thank you Sir, it Worked...
I learnt my mistakes...